# How to get access to the full Row in Spark UDF function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are using plain SQL syntax to transform the data and have custom UDF functions. 
Example:

```
UDF_FUNCTION(String, Int)
```

This function could produce exceptions and we would like to provide detailed error for the user. In the row we have information about the file and row_id, that is why we want to access a full row in mentioned UDF to provide detailed error with file_uuid and row_id for example. Does someone have any idea about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can can use ***struct*** function to send all columns to the udf. You have to use **Row** type as the input parameter in the udf´s anonymous function. Something like the example below:

```
  def udf_full_row = udf { (row: Row) =>
    val your_transformed_int = (row.getAs[Int]("value as int") + 1)
    your_transformed_int
  }

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct}

  val df_test : DataFrame = ???
  val cols_array = df_test.columns.map(col(_))

  df_test.withColumn("your_new_colun", udf_full_row(struct(cols_array: _*)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this approach, but the problem is that we receive transformation as user input and as plain SQL. In that case, we should use something line regex to replace UDF call with additional params(we don't like such approach and would like to receive access to other columns in more elegant way).

Comment: You could use some Sql Parsers available to generate the transformations. Something like https://github.com/stephentu/scala-sql-parser

Comment: Thank you! I used SparkSqlParser and it helped me to add additional parameters.